# Transfer db records from one Oracle schema to another with the same structure generating insert statements script

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to export certain tables records and import them into another schema with the same structure. First I have created a function:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GENERATE_INSERT_STATEMENTS (p_table_name VARCHAR2)
       RETURN VARCHAR2
```

that generates sql query which execution returns generated insert statements where for `ID` column value `table_sequence.nextVal` is used.

Also I have created  a PLSQL procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE export_query_res_to_file(p_sql IN VARCHAR2,
                                                     p_dir IN VARCHAR2,
                                                     p_file IN VARCHAR2                                    )
```

which writes `p_sql`query results into `p_file`. So if we want to generate insert sql script for table `table_a` we call:

```
declare res nvarchar2(32767);
begin
  res:= GENERATE_INSERT_STATEMENTS('table_a');
  export_query_res_to_file(res,'MY_DIR','sql_script.txt');
  end;
```

This is fine for independent tables. But I have no idea how to handle FKs in case of one-to-many and many-to-many relations. Any idea would help...

Comment: Are the two schemas in the same database, or does this have to be done via a file transfer?

Comment: The two schemas are in different databases on two different servers but their structure is the same. Actually we have deployed the same app on two platforms. After we create some objects via UI on one platform, which is time consuming process,  we want to export them to another one.

Comment: You might be better off with a proper db synchronization tool. SQL Developer, TOAD, PL/SQL Developer all have "compare schema" functionality that can generate SQL-scripts to synchronize schemas in different databases. I think that is better than building your own synchronization code.

Comment: Have you consider using datapump via db_link?